# Is Franz Oberhauser related to the original Blofeld?

Tags: character, james-bond, spectre

Note: spoilers for Spectre ahead!

In Spectre, we meet Franz Oberhauser (Christoph Waltz). He later reveals he now goes by the name "Ernst Blofeld", and has a scar just like the original Blofeld. But he also states he took the name "from his mother's side".

My question is, is Oberhauser a descendent of the original Blofeld (from On Her Majesty's Secret Service among others), or is he supposed to be the same Blofeld character?

I know the Daniel Craig series of Bond films are a reboot/prequel of sorts. Is Spectre showing the "genesis" of the character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. He's supposed to be the same character. The timeline of the story arc is all over the place now but Spectre could be regarded as a prequel to the series before Daniel Craig. Some say a reboot but apparently its all supposed to be the same story. This falls apart because of Judi Denchs M, Bond's previous encounters with Spectre and Blofeld etc though.